# Integrate Function over Points on a Cube

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration, geometry-surface

I have a set of points that all sit on a cube with side lengths a1, a2 and a3. I obtain the points by constructing a unit sphere, and then, for each point, I determine which face of a 'unit cube' the point is closest to and change the coordinate of that direction to either + or - 1. In the case of a1=a2=a3=2. I get something that looks like this:

[image]

What's the easiest/fastest way to integrate some function (scalar or vector) over this cube with some scipy or numpy function? I guess the normal for each point is very easy to construct. However, since the transformation I described above is not really smooth, I guess I'm looking for a numerical procedure. Should I just take the 6 faces, do a Delaunay triangulation and integrate, or are the better, more straight forward, ways?

Comment: It'd not really clear what your domain is. The convex hull of these points?

Comment: Hey Nico, I'd not call it convex hull, but they all live on the cube with side length 2, centered at 0.

Comment: Then it's not clear what the points have to do with it. You just want to integrate a function over the surface of a cube, right?

Comment: Yes, I now that I can use some integration scheme for an arbitrary sets of points. I was just wondering if knowing how I constructed the points that sit on the cube, I can use this (symmetry/construction) to make a smarter choice than e.g. triangulation, etc.

Comment: Integration points are never "arbitrary", but explicitly chosen to fulfill certain criteria. Triangulation doesn't have much to do with it either. If you're after Gaussian integration, once you've chosen your points the corresponding weights are retrieved in a least-squares solve, but you probably won't get very far with your choice.

Comment: But I can choose some interpolation that gives me the integration weights. E.g. on each of the six faces.

Comment: No need for interpolation. You just need the point coordinates to get the weights. But, like I said, the points are probably not well chosen. You're better off with one of the existing schemes for the rectangle, https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy#quadrilateral-c2.